# IPSec VPN Client Linux

Tags: linux, vpn, ipsec

I have a SonicWall router with an IP address @public_A. Behind this router is a LAN 192.168.2.0/24.
On an other hand, I have a Linux Ubuntu machine with IP address @public_B

My aim is to realise a VPN IPSec client for Linux so I am able to send messages from my Linux Client machine to the 192.168.2.0/24 LAN.

This client already exists for Windows machines, developped by SonicWall, but not for Linux machines.

I decided to configure an OpenSwan tunnel in order to connect to this LAN, following advice of many posts on the internet.

ipsec.conf :

```
conn sonicwall
        type=tunnel
        left=public_B
        leftid=@yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
        leftxauthclient=yes
        right=public_A
        rightsubnet=192.168.2.0/24
        rightxauthserver=yes
        rightid=@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        keyingtries=0
        pfs=no
        aggrmode=yes
        auto=add
        auth=esp
        esp=aes256-sha1
        #phase2alg=aes256-sha1
        ike=aes256-sha1;modp1536
        authby=secret
        leftxauthusername=USER
        #xauth=yes
        keyexchange=ike
```

Logs at launch :

```
~# ipsec whack --name sonicwall --initiate
002 "sonicwall" #9: initiating Aggressive Mode #9, connection "sonicwall"
112 "sonicwall" #9: STATE_AGGR_I1: initiate
003 "sonicwall" #9: ignoring Vendor ID payload [Sonicwall 1 (TZ 170 Standard?)]
003 "sonicwall" #9: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]
003 "sonicwall" #9: received Vendor ID payload [RFC 3947] method set to=109 
003 "sonicwall" #9: received Vendor ID payload [Dead Peer Detection]
003 "sonicwall" #9: received Vendor ID payload [XAUTH]
002 "sonicwall" #9: Aggressive mode peer ID is ID_FQDN: '@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
003 "sonicwall" #9: NAT-Traversal: Result using RFC 3947 (NAT-Traversal): i am NATed
002 "sonicwall" #9: transition from state STATE_AGGR_I1 to state STATE_AGGR_I2
004 "sonicwall" #9: STATE_AGGR_I2: sent AI2, ISAKMP SA established {auth=OAKLEY_PRESHARED_KEY cipher=aes_256 prf=oakley_sha group=modp1536}
002 "sonicwall" #9: XAUTH: Answering XAUTH challenge with user='USER'
002 "sonicwall" #9: transition from state STATE_XAUTH_I0 to state STATE_XAUTH_I1
004 "sonicwall" #9: STATE_XAUTH_I1: XAUTH client - awaiting CFG_set
003 "sonicwall" #9: ignoring informational payload, type IPSEC_INITIAL_CONTACT msgid=00000000
003 "sonicwall" #9: received and ignored informational message
002 "sonicwall" #9: XAUTH: Successfully Authenticated
002 "sonicwall" #9: transition from state STATE_XAUTH_I0 to state STATE_XAUTH_I1
004 "sonicwall" #9: STATE_XAUTH_I1: XAUTH client - awaiting CFG_set
002 "sonicwall" #10: initiating Quick Mode PSK+ENCRYPT+TUNNEL+UP+AGGRESSIVE+IKEv2ALLOW+SAREFTRACK {using isakmp#9 msgid:489fb919 proposal=AES(12)_256-SHA1(2)_160 pfsgroup=no-pfs}
117 "sonicwall" #10: STATE_QUICK_I1: initiate
002 "sonicwall" #10: transition from state STATE_QUICK_I1 to state STATE_QUICK_I2
004 "sonicwall" #10: STATE_QUICK_I2: sent QI2, IPsec SA established tunnel mode {ESP=>0xff65c149 <0x6de1b3e3 xfrm=AES_256-HMAC_SHA1 NATOA=none NATD=none DPD=none}
```

NB : no route had been added after that in my routing table.

My tunnel seems to be fully functionnal but : I cannot send any message to the LAN behind the router. I have no idea how to use the tunnel I have just set in order to send at least a ping to a machine in the LAN. How should I do ?

You can also give me advice to reach my goal, even if it is not by using OpenSwan

Thanks for reading and helping.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any new network interfaces after you've successfully authenticated? Check `ip addr` to see if you have any `ppp0` or similar interfaces.

I'm not sure about your case since your authentication method is different from what I've configured in the past (pre-shared key openswan + user/pass xl2tpd) but, if there are any similarities, running `ipsec auto --up ${connection_name}` normally establishes the tunnel using the preshared key for authentication but without bringing up the interface, at which point I have to tell xl2tpd to connect, which authenticates with the user and password, then creates the interface `ppp0`.

What's your output for `ipsec verify` (after starting the openswan service)?

Comment: I do not have anny ppp0 new interface. Actually, if I could have one, that would be great.

According to you, I should start a xl2tpd. You are right that the 

> ipsec auto --up ${connection_name}

 does not bring up the interface.

my ipsec verify shows all [OK], less [N/A] for SAref kernel support, and Opportunistic Encryption Support [DISABLED]